# Force Remote Merge Between Two Branches Even With Conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working on a project and I've used `bitbucket`'s git repo in it. I want to merge a branch (let's call it my-branch) to master but due to some conflicts, I'm unable to do so. Some files in `bin/` and `gen/` directories (I know I should have added them in the `.gitignore` list but I was/am new to `git` so I didn't know about it back then.

My question is, is there a way to force merge these files locally (keeping the changes in my-branch) and then `push` these changes to the remote repo resulting in master getting merged in my-branch.

Apperciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The best solution is to `git rm bin gen` and add these to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: I did add these directories in my `.gitignore` but they don't seem to be excluded. Because whenever I build my project and run a `git status`, I see them in the list of changed files.

Comment: remote force merge may even conflict, try cloning one and do stash pop

Comment: They are not excluded because they are in your repo. You need to `git rm` them, too.

Comment: @DIVA How to do that?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But whenever I'd run an `git status` command they'd still get added with default `--all` switch to the commit and the push, too.

Comment: if there is exsting repo on ur local machince..do 1. git stash. 2.git pull 2. git pop and is any confilts resolve it locally and push the merged code

Comment: umm...what do you mean by "default `--add` switch`?

Answer (score 0):

try this, when on master branch:

```
git merge branch -X my-branch
```

Comment: And how to reflect these changes remotely?

Comment: git push origin master --force

Comment: What's the risk here? I ran it `git merge master -X my-branch` and it gave me a notice "Already up-to-date."

Comment: Sorry I was thinking something else.... but check the edited post You can also delete the remote and push again the local

Comment: What's the point of using git if I've to delete my remote repo every time I encounter a conflict?

Comment: Wouldn't that just push the master? How to merge my-branch into master on remote?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove the `bin` and `gen` directories from your repo. The most straight-forward way to do this is by running `git rm bin gen` and adding these directories to your `.gitignore`. (Don't forget to commit the changes to `.gitignore`.)

If you want to remove `bin` and `gen` from your history entirely, you will need to use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch).

Comment: I did that. Now shall I just `push` the `.gitignore` changes to remote or everything? (Including the indication that files and directories have been removed)